# Why are modules also rings in the HOL-Algebra library?

Tags: isabelle, isabelle-hol

We would like to use vectors and matrices (2x2 and 3x3) in a project, and have found the Jordan Normal Form AFP entry (`Matrix.thy`) which provides a concrete implementation. It relies on the `HOL-Algebra` implementation of modules but this theory seems really bizarre, as though it gets everything the wrong way around.

To have this question self-contained, recall that in the simplest case a module $M$ is typically defined over a commutative ring $(R, +_R, \cdot_R)$, such that $(M, +_M)$ is an Abelian group and there is a 'multiplicative' action $\circ : R \times M \rightarrow M$ which distributes over both $+_M$ and $+_R$, is associative w.r.t $\cdot_R$, and for which $1_R$ is also an identity.

This definition may be generalized to a module $M$ over an Abelian Group $(G, +_G)$ instead of a ring. In that case we still require $(M, +_M)$ to be an Abelian group, and there to be an action $\circ : G \times M \rightarrow M$ but it only needs to distribute over both additions.

Now, [`HOL-Algebra/Module.thy`](https://www.isa-afp.org/browser_info/current/HOL/HOL-Algebra/Module.html) claims to define "modules over an Abelian group." There is a record of what an `('a, 'b) module` is  with an action `smult : ['a, 'b] => 'b`. This is followed by a locale `module` which seems alright (but clearly defines modules over a ring, not over an Abelian group). However, weirdly, the record `('a, 'b) module` requires `'b`, i.e. the module itself, to be a ring. In my understanding, if anything, we should require `'a` to be a ring (namely $R$ in the definition above!). Better yet, `'b` should be an Abelian group, and in order to define modules over an Abelian group as claimed, `'a` should also be such.

As a consequence, for the Jordan Normal Form entry to [show that](https://www.isa-afp.org/theories/jordan_normal_form/#Matrix.html#Matrix.module_vec_def%7Cfact) for `'a :: semiring_1`, the type `'a vec` of vectors over `'a` forms a module*, they have to specify `mult = undefined, one = undefined` in the definition of the record. Given HOL-Algebra as it is, this makes sense as there is no natural multiplication or multiplicative identity in the space of generic vectors.

Is there a reason for these akward definitions?

[*To be very precise, a module over a semiring is only required to be a commutative monoid not a full Abelian group.]